# for loop ignoring boolean if statement

Tags: java, android

The foreach loop is completely ignoring my if statement.

```
        for(InfoBox infoBox : mAbilities)
        {
            if(infoBox.CheckPressed(event));
            {
                //This is being outputted each time, even if the if statement returns false.
                System.out.println(infoBox.getName());
            }

            System.out.println(infoBox.CheckPressed(event));
            System.out.println(infoBox.getName());
        }
```

Comment: That's why you should respect [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) and put opening brace in same line as if / for etc.

Comment: You have a "System.out.println(infoBox.getName());" outside the if{} in the for{}. Are you sure that is not the print you are seeing?...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've prematurely terminated your `if` statement with a semicolon:

```
if(infoBox.CheckPressed(event));  // <-- remove the semicolon
```

This makes the following block a freestanding block that will always execute.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is something which you must have done unintentionally.....

`if(infoBox.CheckPressed(event));`

Please **remove** the `semicolon` in the above `if` Statement

Answer (score 2):

You should remove semicolon from if statement

```
if(infoBox.CheckPressed(event));
```